# pandas - select index with a list of integer

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe such as follow:

```
import numpy as np
pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(20,2))
```

I would like to remove from it the rows with index contained in the list:

```
list_ = [0,4,5,6,18]
```

How would I go about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
df = df.drop(list_)
print (df)
           0         1
1   0.311202  0.435528
2   0.225144  0.322580
3   0.165907  0.096357
7   0.925991  0.362254
8   0.777936  0.552340
9   0.445319  0.672854
10  0.919434  0.642704
11  0.751429  0.220296
12  0.425344  0.706789
13  0.708401  0.497214
14  0.110249  0.910790
15  0.972444  0.817364
16  0.108596  0.921172
17  0.299082  0.433137
19  0.234337  0.163187
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
remove = df.index.isin(list_)
df[~remove]
```

Or just:

```
df[~df.index.isin(list_)]
```